Two different reaction pathways that explain the non-neutrality of a dissolved salt
So the problem is this: is the sodium acetate acidic, basic or neutral?
One of my textbooks (ATAR Notes chemistry) says in solution, acetate simply (due to its negative charge) accepts protons and produces hydroxide ions
$$\ce{CH3COO- + H2O <=> CH3COOH + OH-} \tag{1}$$
Hence the [$\ce{OH-}$] increases so solution is basic. Hence acetate is a basic anion.
However, my teacher's notes say:
\begin{align}
\ce{CH3COO- + H3O+ &<=> CH3COOH + H2O (l)} \tag{2}\\
\ce{H3O+ + OH- &<=> H2O + H2O} \tag{3}
\end{align}
that the acetate ions will be released into solution and thus, to decrease their concentration, some of the $\ce{CH3COO-}$ ions react with $\ce{H3O+}$ (LCP). Consequently, $\ce{H3O+}$ drops and more water ionizes and thus [$\ce{OH-}$] increases (LCP). So the acetate ion is a basic anion.
Which pathway, that leads to the formation of basic solution due to the acetate ion, is the correct one?

Avoid using zeros instead of letters O in chemical formulas. It hints carelessness or ignorance and none of them is taken lightly. // You are not the first asking about this topic. It seems you did not do searching properly.

Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions

Both approaches by Percival are correct. They are really similar. The second is a rewritten variation of the first pathway, using other words.

Both pathways are correct and simultaneous. Their equilibrium constants are related. As the reactions are written, the constants are Kb,  1/Ka, 1/Kw,  where Ka . Kb = Kw = 10^(-14) at 25 deg C..

@poutnik would you care to share the link where this topic was asked elsewhere? I simply cannot find it.

You may find useful reviewing the targetted search results like
site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org hydrolysis reactions salt weak acid

All reactions that you have provided are correct.
These reactions have the general schema, following Broensted-Lawry concept of acids and bases:
$$\ce{acid1 + base2 <=>[H+ exchange] base1 + acid2}$$
or
$$\ce{HA + B <=> A- + BH+}$$
when the abstract $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ components may be both neutral or charged.
The acid may be in your case any particle providing $\ce{H+}$ ion, like $\ce{CH3COOH}$, $\ce{H3O+}$ or even (very weak one) $\ce{H2O}$.
The base may be any particle accepting $\ce{H+}$ ion: $\ce{CH3COO-}$, $\ce{OH-}$ or even (very weak one) $\ce{H2O}$.
Each of combinations has its own equilibrium constant, that can be derived from respective dissociation constants of acids or bases.
$\ce{CH3COO-}$ as the base reacts simultaneously with two acids:

the weak acid $\ce{H2O}$ that is in huge excess.

$\ce{CH3COO-(aq) + H2O(l) <=> CH3COOH(aq) + OH-(aq)}$


the strong acid $\ce{H3O+}$ that is sparse.

$\ce{CH3COO-(aq) + H3O+(aq) <=> CH3COOH(aq) + H2O(l)}$




The $K_a$ of $\ce{CH3COOH}$ at room temperature is about:
$$K_a=1.8\cdot10^{-5}$$
That means the $K_b$ for the acetate ion is:
$$K_b=\frac{K_w}{K_a}=\frac{10^{-14}}{1.8\cdot10^{-5}}=5.56\cdot10^{-10}$$
Now we can analyze the equilibrium system that forms when adding pure acetate into water. Assuming we initially start with $0.1M$ (i.e. a high enough concentration for water auto-ionization to be reasonably negligible):
$$\ce{CH3COO-(aq) +H2O(l)<=>CH3COOH(aq) +OH-(aq)}$$
At equilibrium, we have the following concentrations:
$$C_{\ce{CH3COO-}}=0.1-x$$
$$C_{\ce{CH3COOH}}=x$$
$$C_{\ce{OH-}}=x$$
Plugging them into the $K_b$ formula:
$$K_b=5.56\cdot10^{-10}=\frac{x^2}{0.1-x}$$
Solving for $x$:
$$x=\pu{7.41\cdot10^{-6}M}$$
So the final concentration of hydroxide would be:
$$C_{\ce{OH-}}=\pu{7.41\cdot10^{-6}M}$$
And the pH of this slightly basic solution would be approximately:
$$\pmb{\pu{pH}=14+\log(7.41\cdot10^{-6})=8.87}$$
If you were to repeat the analysis with $\frac{1}{10^4}$ fraction for the initial concentration of acetate, you would have to include the auto-ionization of water, and the resulting pH of this practically neutral solution would be approximately:
$$\pmb{\pu{pH}=14+\log(3.96\cdot10^{-8}+10^{-7})=7.14}$$

Sam202's text is OK. But it is not an answer to the question.
